# Consulta mysql cantidad de productos por fecha

Tags: mysql, subconsultas

```
SELECT p.descripcion as producto,ped.cantidad as cantidad, fac.fecha as fecha 
from producto p 
inner join pedido ped on (p.id=ped.fk_producto) 
inner join factura fac on (ped.fk_factura=fac.id);
```

- -prod1 1 fechax
- prod1 1 fechax
- prod1 2 fechay
- prod2 3 fechax
- prod2 3 fechax
- prod3 5  fechaw

Hola, esta es mi consulta y me trae los productos , la cantidad y la fecha de la compra; sin embargo, necesito la cantidad de productos por fecha:

- prod1 2 fecha x
- prod1 2 fecha y
- prod2 6 fecha x
- prod3 5 fecha w

Intente realizarlo con la funcion sum() pero cuenta todo, intente agruparlo con group by fecha, pero necesito que de acuerdo al producto si es necesario se repita la fecha.

Agradezco sugerencias

Comment: Te podriamos ayudar mas si pones como te esta regresando actualmente tu información para darnos una idea, la solución podria ser facil con una suma de cantidad y agrupar por el producto y fecha pero si la fecha tiene segundos eso puede hacer que no se realice correctamente

Comment: Gracias Edgar, efectivamente esa es la respuesta, debía agrupar por múltiples columnas y los segundos no son problema porque luego voy a tomar solo el mes.